# How do I transfer macros to Excel 2019?

Tags: excel, vba

I created Excel macros many years ago.  I am transferring them to Excel 2019.

In Excel 2019, I've saved my macros in one .xlsm.  How do I have all other Excel .xlsx files use those macros?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Use a [personal workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566).

Comment: one more link : https://trumpexcel.com/personal-macro-workbook/

Answer (score 0):

The key is to save the macro to PERSONAL.XLSB.  Now it works fine.

Comment: PERSONAL.XLSB is located at C:\Users\?laptop\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART